# Google Code: Force comment on commit

Tags: svn, commit, google-code

I just started using Google code hosting and am a beginner at working with Subversion. I was wondering if there is a way to enforce a rule that no commits can be made without comments. I was researching into it, and I did find a way to do this on subversion - it involves [creating a pre-commit hook](http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/165-tools/1678-how-to-check-commit-comments-on-svn-commit.html). But I don't think I can do this in Google code (or am I wrong about this?)

Do you know how I can enforce this? Thanks!

Comment: yeah you're right about Google not being able to do pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this to the Google Code issues list as a feature request and it was reviewed and accepted as an enhancement request. But on the mean while, they provided the suggestion of using the **email on commit** option. This way if someone committed without comments, you can can at least notice it right away and let them know.